# Having trouble finding certain <div> tags using CSS Selectors

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape information from a website using a CSS Selector in order to get a specific text element but have come across a problem. I try to search for my desired portion of the website but my program is telling me that it does not exist. My program returns an empty list.

I am using the requests and lxml libraries and am using CSS Selectors to do my HTML Scraping. I have Python 3.7. I try searching for the part of the website that I need with a selector and it is not appearing. I have also tried using XPath but that has failed as well. I have tried using the following selector:

```
div#showtimes
```

When I use this selector, I get the following result:

```
[<Element div at 0x3bf6f60>]
```

I get the expected result, which is the desired  element. When I try to go one step further and access the  element nested inside of the div#showtimes element (see below), I get an empty list.

```
div#showtimes div
```

I get the following result:

```
[]
```

Through inspection of the website's HTML, I know that there is a nested  element within the div#showtimes element. This problem has occurred on other web pages as well. I am using the code below.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

# Set URL
url = "http://www.fridleytheatres.com/location/7425/Paramount-7-Theatres- 
Showtimes"

# Get HTML from page
page = requests.get(url)
data = html.fromstring(page.text)

# Set up CSSSelector
sel = CSSSelector('div#showtimes div')
# Apply Selector
results = sel(data)
print(results)
```

I expect the output to be a list containing a  element, but it is returning an empty list [].

Comment: On the page you're loading, `<div id="showtimes">` is empty. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXaF6.png Not sure what else to say.

Comment: @MrLister This is what I am seeing when I inspect the page: https://imgur.com/6DpDyil

Comment: The website uses JavaScript to fill the div, so if you load only the HTML (without running the script), it won't get filled and you won't see anything.

Comment: @MrLister Is there a way that I can run the script while I load the HTML so that I have access to that information?

Comment: Also, thank you. That answers my question for why it will not show up within the <div> tag.

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry; that will take someone with more Python knowledge than me.

Comment: You would need selenium or headless chrome for that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're attempting to get a `div` element which is a child of `div#showtimes`. Try using `div#showtimes > div`.

Comment: With a CSSSelector, the '>' is not needed. I can immediately follow the previous div tag with another div tag, like so: div div (This is from my understanding, and has worked for me for all other situations except this one)